# IncomingNumber from PhoneStateListener::onCallStateChanged is Empty On Samsung A5 ~Android

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with **PhoneStateListener::onCallStateChanged** that always has an empty incomingNumber when I use this particular **Samsung A5 (Kitkat 4.4.4)** device. And it doesnt happen when I use another devices which means incomingNumber is not empty when I use other devices.

I've set this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

This is my PhoneStateListener class:

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    boolean wasRinging = false;
    boolean accepted = false;
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        penelpon = incomingNumber;
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Incoming: "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // called when someone is ringing to this phone
            wasRinging = true;
            ada_panggilan = true;
            //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Incoming: "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            // accepted
            if(wasRinging){
                //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Diterima: "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SafedriveActivity.is_call_accepted = true;
                accepted = true;
            }
            ada_panggilan = true;
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            if(wasRinging){     // ditolak, kirim pesan
                ada_panggilan = true;
                if(!accepted) {
                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ditolak: ngirim pesan ke: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SafedriveActivity.is_call_accepted = false;
                    if(Statics.preferences.getBoolean(Statics.IS_SMS_AUTO_REPLY_ENABLED_PHONE,true)) {
                        sendMessage();
                    }
                }else{
                    //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Habis diterima, ditutup: "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SafedriveActivity.is_call_accepted = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

in this case, **penelpon** is empty.

Why is this happening to only Samsung A5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue with android emulators with number being empty when I was telneting in via "telnet host port" and then issuing "gcm call 18005551212". I tried such on a live phone and the same code then started working and populating with actual number. Just wanted to share the data point.